# Will Windows Web Services API be available within Windows for IoT?

Tags: windowsondevices

What is recommended set of API’s for communicating between device and the cloud? Is the Windows Web Services API the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your timeframe and the service that you are trying to connect to. We are working to bring the [Intelligent Systems Service](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/intelligent-systems-service.aspx) to the Windows for IoT solution, which includes a client agent and associated APIs.

Outside of this - it's Windows! - so you're free to use any of the supported Windows APIs for connecting to services (we'll be working to bring the universal app-model to Windows for IoT in the future).

Pranish, 
Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Without the marketing speak, does this mean DPWS, or some form of .Net remoting? Please don't say 'announced at Build' I wasn't there and didn't read nor care to read the transcripts. Does the universal model include .Net remoting functionality or not? 'Will be working' is not much of a commitment, so I have to take that with a grain of salt.